# Django not serving HTML table in template (word counter web app)

Tags: python, django

**Summary:**

Django is not rendering a basic 2 column by 11 row HTML table containing the top 10 most commonly used words in a large text file (Alice and Wonderland which is a public domain work). But right now the table is empty.

**Details:**

The table currently rendering on the web page looks like this, [see here on imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNc0G.jpg). In that pic, notice the bottom right corner, the table is empty.

The fully populated word counter table and its contents render when a web user navigates to  `http://127.0.0.1:8000/counters`. [See here on imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etnN9.jpg).

However the problem in the second pic is that the blog post 'lorem ipsum' content is empty.

Here is my parent top level **[urls.py](https://github.com/enoren5/CC_Redact_Iter3/blob/533cd5e798df4de4cb935ca3a74650d391ebcdd4/CC_Redact_Iter3/urls.py)**:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
   path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
   # path('', include('mortems.urls')),
   path('', include('redactors.urls')),
   path('', include('posts.urls')),   
   path('', include('counters.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Here is my `counters` app’s **[views.py](https://github.com/enoren5/CC_Redact_Iter3/blob/533cd5e798df4de4cb935ca3a74650d391ebcdd4/counters/views.py)**:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from collections import Counter
import re
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

def counters(request, text=""):
   """
   This function processes the top 10 most common words in a text file and then renders them.
   """
   text = open("counters/Alice.txt", "r").read().lower()
   stoplist = stopwords.words('english')
   stoplist.extend(["said","gutenberg", "could", "would",])
   clean = []
   for word in re.split(r"\W+",text):
       if word not in stoplist:
           clean.append(word)
   top_10 = Counter(clean).most_common(10)
   return render(request, 'alls/landings.html', {'top_10': top_10})
```

Here is my `counters` app’s **[urls.py](https://github.com/enoren5/CC_Redact_Iter3/blob/533cd5e798df4de4cb935ca3a74650d391ebcdd4/counters/urls.py)**:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
   path('counters', views.counters, name='counters'),
]
```

Take note of the first argument inside the path function. That is the problem because now web visitors see the table when they navigate to `127.0.0.1:8000/counters` but I am trying to make Django serve the table when the user navigates to `127.0.0.1:8000/`or `127.0.0.1:8000/home`. So when I change that first `‘counters’` argument to `‘home’` or `‘’` (leaving it blank) then the table doesn’t render at all.

To conclude, what I am trying to do is have Django serve the `counters` function and pass in the `top_ten` dictionary when rendering the `alls/landings.html` template when the website visitor navigates to either `http://127.0.0.1:8000/home` or `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`. That is what I am trying to accomplish. But instead right now to see the table, the user needs  to visit `http://127.0.0.1:8000/counters` where the blog post content is absent.

There is no traceback in my Django server logs, so I don’t have very many Google search terms to work with.

By the way, for what it is worth, here is my abridged (reduced) HTML table as it appears inside my **[templates/alls/landings.html](https://github.com/enoren5/CC_Redact_Iter3/blob/533cd5e798df4de4cb935ca3a74650d391ebcdd4/templates/alls/landings.html)**:

```
  <h1>Counting the words!</h1>
  This should only show inside landing.html
  <div class="">
   <table>
       <tr><th>Word</th> <th>Quantity</th></tr> 
       {% for word, count in top_10 %}
       <tr> <td>{{word}} </td><td>{{count}} </td></tr>
       {% endfor %}
   </table>
  </div>
```

Here is **[a complete static snapshot](https://github.com/enoren5/CC_Redact_Iter3/tree/533cd5e798df4de4cb935ca3a74650d391ebcdd4)** of my full source code on GitHub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eureka! It’s working!

Since last time, `counters/views.py` has been rearranged. The functions contained inside that view have been moved into the `posts/views.py`. Even the `top_word_counts` function has been moved into a new file at `posts/utils.py`. Here is a screenshot on imgur showing the table with the most commonly appearing words in Alice.txt (bottom left corner):  https://i.stack.imgur.com/dK5a1.jpg

You might notice traces of new functionality. For example not only does my app count the contents of Alice.txt but now the app also counts the most commonly appearing words inside the blog posts (right now lorem ipsum placeholder content).

With all of those changes in mind, here is my working `posts/views.py`:

```
import operator
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render, get_object_or_404
from posts.models import Posts
from .utils import top_word_counts

def posts(request):
    posts = Posts.objects.all().order_by('-pub_date')
    context = {'posts':posts}

    post_string = ''
    for post in posts:
        post_string += post.body

    post_words = top_word_counts(post_string.lower())
    alice_words = top_word_counts(
        open("counters/Alice.txt", "r").read().lower())

    context.update({
        'post_words': post_words,
        'alice_words': alice_words
    })

    return render(request, 'alls/landings.html', context)
```

Here is my new `posts/utils.py`:

```
import re
from collections import Counter
from nltk.corpus import stopwords


def top_word_counts(text):
    # text = open("counters/Alice.txt", "r").read().lower()

    stoplist = stopwords.words('english')
    stoplist.extend(["said", "gutenberg", "could", "would", ])
    clean = []
    for word in re.split(r"\W+", text):
        if word not in stoplist:
            clean.append(word)
    top_10 = Counter(clean).most_common(10)

    return top_10
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the way you have designed your top level urls is the problem. If you want the user to redirect to your counter view as soon as he/she visits the homepage, you need to change the parent urls.py to something like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [
   path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
   # path('', include('mortems.urls')),
   path('redactors', include('redactors.urls')),
   path('posts', include('posts.urls')),   
   path('', include('counters.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

The problem in your version is that as soon as a user visits homepage, he is directed towards redactors.urls as that is the first match found for the homepage url.

Next, you will need to change the counters.urls to:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
   path('', views.counters, name='counters'),
]
```

This will redirect the user directly towards the counter view when he/she visits your web homepage.

Alternatively, if you want the counter view to be served on `http://127.0.0.1:8000/home`, then you can change the parent `urls.py` to:

```
path('home/', include('counters.urls')),
```

Comment: Thank you @Hatim but I’m trying to get the `counters` HTML table to appear when Django serves the `landings.html` template rather than being served  by itself in a separate template template. The three apps (`redactors`, `posts`, `counters`) should all show on the website’s landing page at `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` and not on separate pages such as `http://127.0.0.1:8000/counters` or `http://127.0.0.1:8000/redactors` which is what your path arguments would do. Next I will update my question to clarify this further.

Comment: ok, so what i understood from your comment is that the counter table is a part of landing page, not the whole landing page, right? You can use AJAX call to render the counter table once the page has been loaded. Let me know if i understood your question correctly.